# Mathematics-Oriented 4-D Glossary?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Is there somewhere a comprehensive glossary of words or phrases describing geometric concepts or objects in the Euclidean (not Einsteinian) fourth dimension? I have seen a glossary which purported to be such, but its terms seemed less like serious mathematics and more like an attempt by some geek to name characters, places or objects in some rôle-playing game (or other such time-suck) he was inventing.

[Nota bene: I note that there is available the tag "3d". How about "4d", as well?]

Comment: Four dimensional geometry is peculiar (compared to lower and higher dimensional), there are some things that occur only in four dimensions, like exotic differential structures, but I don't think there's anything to warrant a significant shift in terminology from arbitrary dimension to dimension four.

Comment: As far as I know, after $3$ dimensions you just prefix everything with hyper-

Comment: @Tomasz \\ Thank you for your response. My question specifically excluded the peculiar treatment accorded the fourth (temporal) dimension by Einsteinian relativity. Yours ...

Comment: @Johanna \\ Thank you for your response. As to the expedient of prefixing "hyper-" to concepts and objects in the lowest three dimensionalities to arrive at similar concepts and objects in 4D, I believe that that procedure would be too limiting and that things peculiar to 4D might be missed. Yours ...

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi: I was talking about geometrical properties related to four-dimensional manifolds, the regular kind, not Minkowski/Lorentzian kind. As far as I understand it, three-plus-one dimensional spacetime is not so different from two-plus-one or even one-plus-one dimensional spacetime. Then again, I have only a very rudimentary understanding of special relativity.